# Receive Prompts from a report using REST services for Pentaho

Tags: rest, pentaho

I was wondering if it is possible to receive the prompts used (with possibly all it's options) in a report using REST services.

What I like to achieve is receiving the prompts and if possible all the options for those prompts in an XML format from any given Pentaho report. I know there are [rest calls](http://javadoc.pentaho.com/bi-platform530/webservice530/) for basic repository listings etc... but I can't seem to find this specific call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get full parameters xml (which includes parameters, parameters values, parameters attributes as far as info which is used to create report prompts) - full parameter info. You need bi server and reporting plugin. The url is:

```
http://localhost:8080/pentaho/api/repos/"%"3Apublic"%"3ASteel"%"20Wheels"%"3AInventory"%"20List"%"20(report).prpt/parameter
```

And we have to pass parameter **renderMode** with value: *PARAMETER*.

Here we call to report under */public/Steel Wheels/Inventory List (reprot).prpt*

or simplifying -

```
"http://localhost:8080/pentaho/api/repos/<path_to_report>.prpt/parameter"
```

You can open browser and inspect requests responses just on fly:

[image]

On a screen is actually parameter requests you are looking for.

Comment: thx, I can't believe it was this simple yet I couldn't find any proper documentation about this specific call. (maybe because it's so simple) but thanks anyway.

Comment: Just pay attention that this request will return parameter xml with default parameter values. After user will select some controls on UI selecting some parameters we will call for report passing this parameters in post/get request. If we need just validate selected parameters - we can fire a request to endpoint described above to receive xml with validated parameters values instead of failed attempt to generate report with invalid parameters.